# Print a document html directly with react-native-print

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, printing, native

The device I refer to is the **Sunmi V2 PRO**. 
I imported and linked the **react-native-print** library in my project.

When I start the RNPrint.print () function passing my html string, it does not print directly, but goes to a screen where I can choose other printers (there is only one) or download the pdf.
Is there a way to skip this screen and start printing directly?

I simply call this in my function:

```
await RNPrint.print({ html })
```

Answer (score 0):

To be onset with you, there is no way to adjust the option of the browser. please don't waste your time. see this link about [printing by using  JS](https://code-examples.net/en/q/6294d6).